# Multiple axis line chart in excel

Tags: excel, charts

I'm looking for a multiple axis line chart similar to the one in the image below, (which is a javascript chart made by amcharts).

Does excel have an option to draw charts line these? Note there are 3 Y axes, and 3 line charts allowing you to compare data.

Is it possible to get more than 3 data points, each with unique axis on one chart ?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to get both the primary and secondary axes on one side of the chart by designating the secondary axis for one of the series.

To get the primary axis on the right side with the secondary axis, you need to set to "High" the Axis Labels option in the Format Axis dialog box for the primary axis.

To get the secondary axis on the left side with the primary axis, you need to set to "Low" the Axis Labels option in the Format Axis dialog box for the secondary axis.

I know of no way to get a third set of axis labels on a single chart. You could fake in axis labels & ticks with text boxes and lines, but it would be hard to get everything aligned correctly.

The more feasible route is that suggested by zx8754: Create a second chart, turning off titles, left axes, etc. and lay it over the first chart. See my very crude mockup which hasn't been fine-tuned yet.

[image: three axis labels chart]

Answer (score 6):

The picture you showd in the question is actually a chart made using JavaScript. It is actually very easy to plot multi-axis chart using JavaScript with the help of 3rd party libraries like HighChart.js or D3.js. Here I propose to use the Funfun Excel add-in which allows you to use JavaScript directly in Excel so you could plot chart like you've showed easily in Excel. Here I made an example using Funfun in Excel.

[image]

You could see in this chart you have one axis of Rainfall at the left side while two axis of Temperature and Sea-pressure level at the right side. This is also a combination of line chart and bar chart for different datasets. In this example, with the help of the Funfun add-in, I used HighChart.js to plot this chart.

Funfun also has an online editor in which you could test your JavaScript code with you data. You could check the detailed code of this example on the link below.

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a43b416b848f771fbcdee2c

> Edit: The content on the previous link has been changed so I posted a
>   new link here. The link below is the original link
>   https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a55dc978dfd67466879eb24

If you are satisfied with the result you achieved in the online editor, you could easily load the result into you Excel using the URL above. Of couse first you need to insert the Funfun add-in from **Insert - My add-ins**. Here are some screenshots showing how you could do this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Disclosure: I'm a developer of Funfun***

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of displaying 3 Y axis see [here](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/PanelUnevenScales.html).

Excel supports Secondary Axis, i.e. only 2 Y axis. Other way would be to chart the 3rd one separately, and overlay on top of the main chart.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to normalize the data. Below are three sets of data with widely varying ranges. In the top chart you can see the variation in one series clearly, in another not so clearly, and the third not at all.

In the second range, I have adjusted the series names to include the data range, using this formula in cell C15 and copying it to D15:E15

=C2&" ("&MIN(C3:C9)&" to "&MAX(C3:C9)&")"

I have normalized the values in the data range using this formula in C15 and copying it to the entire range C16:E22

=100*(C3-MIN(C$3:C$9))/(MAX(C$3:C$9)-MIN(C$3:C$9))

In the second chart, you can see a pattern: all series have a low in January, rising to a high in March, and dropping to medium-low value in June or July.

You can modify the normalizing formula however you need:

=100*C3/MAX(C$3:C$9)

=C3/MAX(C$3:C$9)

=(C3-AVERAGE(C$3:C$9))/STDEV(C$3:C$9)

etc.

[image: Normalizing Data]

Answer (score 0):

Taking the answer above as guidance;

I made an extra graph for "hours worked by month", then copy/special-pasted it as a 'linked picture' for use **under** my other graphs.  in other words, I copy pasted my existing graphs over the linked picture made from my new graph with the new axis..  And because it is a linked picture it always updates.

Make it easy on yourself though, make sure you copy an existing graph to build your 'picture' graph - then delete the series or change the data source to what you need as an extra axis.  That way you won't have to mess around resizing.

The results were not too bad considering what I wanted to achieve; basically a list of incident frequency bar graph, with a performance tread line, and then a solid 'backdrop' of hours worked.

Thanks to the guy above for the idea!

Comment: You refer to "the answer above". There are two answers. Could you please edit your answer and clarify which answer you mean, for example, by including the name of the poster?

Answer (score 0):

Best and Free ( maybe only) solution for this is google sheets.
i don't know whether it plots as u expected or not but certainly you can draw multiple axes.

Regards

keerthan