# Secondary axes Excel 2007

Tags: excel, graph

I have made a scatter plot, and I want to add a secondary x axis and a secondary y axis. Is that possible on excel 2007 or 2010? I only seem to find tutorials that tell me how to add a secondary x axis or a secondary y axis. Not both.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrmy6.png)

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200079/multiple-axis-line-chart-in-excel) help? It's kind of hard to tell with such little info, but does that get you on the right path?

Comment: I just want to make a graph in a box. Instead of only showing the x and y-axes, I want the plot area to be surrounded by axes on four sides.

Comment: Can I make a graph where the variation is shown on four sides of the plot area instead on only two?(the x and y axes?)

Comment: Can you perhaps post some sample data/mock-up, and what you expect the graph to look like?

Comment: I have edited the original question to post a picture. That is what I want the axes of my graph to look like. Would I be able to do that on excel?

Comment: That looks like a regular scatter graph - what about it deviates from a "normal" graph?

Comment: I am talking about the axes. If I were to plot the same graph in excel, I would only get the x-axis and the y-axis. Not the other two axes parallen to these two.

Comment: ***OH***, are you just wanting the tick marks? Those don't look like true "second" axes, but rather just a visual cue to help your eye as you look vertical/horizontal...

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I would like. Can I do that in excel?

Comment: See [this page](http://www.andypope.info/tips/tip005.htm), that should help. You can hide the values from showing, but it'll still show the tick marks. I assume you do the same, just for X axis.

Comment: I did that! But I can't seem to be able to do it for both x and y axes simultaneously.

Comment: So, that is not possible?